# struggling to implement prawn-rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf

I am currently trying this [`prawn-rails`](https://github.com/Whoops/prawn-rails) gem. Please note this is not the famous [`gem 'prawn'`](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn).

Following `prawn-rails` instructions per se (correctly I hope!), so far, I have:

**In Users' Controller**

```
  def test 
    @users = User.all
  end
```

**In Users' Index View**

`<%= link_to "Download PDF", users_test_path(:format=>:pdf) %>`

**In views/users/test.pdf.prawn**

```
prawn_document do |pdf|
  @users.each {|u| pdf.text u }
end
```

**In routes**

`get "users/test"`

Yet, whenever I attempt to click on the `Download PDF` link in the user's index, this is what I get:

```
NoMethodError at /users/test.pdf

undefined method `encode' for #<User:0x007fc6fadb0380>
Did you mean?  encode_with
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Changed my **views/users/test.pdf.prawn** to this:

```
prawn_document do |pdf|

    pdf.font_size 25 
    pdf.text 'List of Users', :style => :bold

  @users.each do |u|  
    pdf.font_size 16
    pdf.text u.first_name + " " + u.last_name
  end

end
```

And then it showed the results